# Cannot dockerize a .net core 3.1 worker service that runs on OS X

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core, dockerfile

I have a .net core 3.1 worker service that properly runs on my local, which is OS X catalina 10.15.

However, when I try to dockerize it, it fails to build on this line of Dockerfile:

```
RUN dotnet build "PostOfficeService.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build
```

My dockerfile is:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:3.1-bionic AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-bionic AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["PostOfficeService.csproj", ""]
RUN dotnet restore "./PostOfficeService.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "PostOfficeService.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "PostOfficeService.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install tzdata
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y tzdata
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "PostOfficeService.dll"]
```

Errors are:

```
Step 9/18 : RUN dotnet build "PostOfficeService.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build
 ---> Running in edea747e95dc
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.5.0+d4cbfca49 for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Restore completed in 46.65 ms for /src/PostOfficeService.csproj.
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.200/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(234,5): error MSB4018: The "ResolvePackageAssets" task failed unexpectedly. [/src/PostOfficeService.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.200/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(234,5): error MSB4018: NuGet.Packaging.Core.PackagingException: Unable to find fallback package folder '/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder'. [/src/PostOfficeService.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.200/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(234,5): error MSB4018:    at NuGet.Packaging.FallbackPackagePathResolver..ctor(String userPackageFolder, IEnumerable`1 fallbackPackageFolders) [/src/PostOfficeService.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.200/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(234,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.NuGetPackageResolver.CreateResolver(IEnumerable`1 packageFolders) [/src/PostOfficeService.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.200/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(234,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.NuGetPackageResolver.CreateResolver(LockFile lockFile) [/src/PostOfficeService.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.200/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(234,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.CacheWriter..ctor(ResolvePackageAssets task) [/src/PostOfficeService.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.200/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(234,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.CacheReader.CreateReaderFromDisk(ResolvePackageAssets task, Byte[] settingsHash) [/src/PostOfficeService.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.200/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(234,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.CacheReader..ctor(ResolvePackageAssets task) [/src/PostOfficeService.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.200/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(234,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.ReadItemGroups() [/src/PostOfficeService.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.200/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(234,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.ExecuteCore() [/src/PostOfficeService.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.200/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(234,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.TaskBase.Execute() [/src/PostOfficeService.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.200/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(234,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute() [/src/PostOfficeService.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.200/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(234,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.ExecuteInstantiatedTask(ITaskExecutionHost taskExecutionHost, TaskLoggingContext taskLoggingContext, TaskHost taskHost, ItemBucket bucket, TaskExecutionMode howToExecuteTask) [/src/PostOfficeService.csproj]

Build FAILED.

/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.200/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(234,5): error MSB4018: The "ResolvePackageAssets" task failed unexpectedly. [/src/PostOfficeService.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.200/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(234,5): error MSB4018: NuGet.Packaging.Core.PackagingException: Unable to find fallback package folder '/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder'. [/src/PostOfficeService.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.200/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(234,5): error MSB4018:    at NuGet.Packaging.FallbackPackagePathResolver..ctor(String userPackageFolder, IEnumerable`1 fallbackPackageFolders) [/src/PostOfficeService.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.200/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(234,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.NuGetPackageResolver.CreateResolver(IEnumerable`1 packageFolders) [/src/PostOfficeService.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.200/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(234,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.NuGetPackageResolver.CreateResolver(LockFile lockFile) [/src/PostOfficeService.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.200/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(234,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.CacheWriter..ctor(ResolvePackageAssets task) [/src/PostOfficeService.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.200/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(234,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.CacheReader.CreateReaderFromDisk(ResolvePackageAssets task, Byte[] settingsHash) [/src/PostOfficeService.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.200/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(234,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.CacheReader..ctor(ResolvePackageAssets task) [/src/PostOfficeService.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.200/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(234,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.ReadItemGroups() [/src/PostOfficeService.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.200/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(234,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.ExecuteCore() [/src/PostOfficeService.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.200/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(234,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.TaskBase.Execute() [/src/PostOfficeService.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.200/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(234,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute() [/src/PostOfficeService.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.200/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(234,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.ExecuteInstantiatedTask(ITaskExecutionHost taskExecutionHost, TaskLoggingContext taskLoggingContext, TaskHost taskHost, ItemBucket bucket, TaskExecutionMode howToExecuteTask) [/src/PostOfficeService.csproj]
    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:01.17
The command '/bin/sh -c dotnet build "PostOfficeService.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Multiple things are coming to my mind.

#### 1: Edit csproj with the below tag:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <RestoreFallbackFolders>clear</RestoreFallbackFolders>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

#### 2: Update Dockerfile.

The dotnet sdk does not have the error folder.

```
root@bd6d24a2e56b:/# cd /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder
bash: cd: /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder: No such file or directory
```

On the step where it fails (I guess in the SDK part) add below docker command:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-bionic AS build
RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder
```

Answer (score 1):

I had an identical error message. The solution that worked for me was posted as a response to a [github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/issues/1649)

In the github issue, user @mthalman states that you need to have Docker ignore the `obj` directory when building an image.

Therefore, update your `.dockerignore` file by appending it with the following contents:

```
**/bin/
**/obj/
```